# MVC HttpGet Page Hard Refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, refresh, http-get

I have an MVC application which dynamically loads and displays inputs for text and checkbox.  Depending upon a users input spans are displayed and hidden on the client side using JQuery which works well.  The problem is if a user hits F5 to refresh the page.  The input values are remembered but the span display/ hide is not.  What I want to do is force the HttpGet action of the controller to always fully reload the page resetting all values.  Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

P

P.S.  I dont want to traverse the document on load in JS to re-hide /re-show the spans based upon the input values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `autocomplete="off"` parameter. It works on both the `input` and `form` element, eg.

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="controller/action" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" autocomplete="off" />
```

It's worth noting though, that this attribute is only valid in HTML5, but works in most browsers regardless of doctype.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input').val('');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a browser auto-complete issue, try adding the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to your form element.